# Удалить двоеточие запятые т.д. PHP

Tags: php

Подскажите как можно удалить из строи все знаки препинания запятые, дефисы, двоеточие и т.д.

Answer (score 1):

```
$str = 'Подскажите как можно удалить из строи все знаки препинания запятые, дефисы, двоеточие и т.д.';
echo preg_replace('/\pP/iu', '', $str);
```

Вывод:

> Подскажите как можно удалить из строи все знаки препинания запятые
>   дефисы двоеточие и тд

Или оставить только нужное: `/[а-я0-9 ]/iu`